# User32 sendmessage works only for some messages

Tags: vb.net, sendmessage, user32

I am looking to send key and mouse events to notepad.exe, however not necessarily have the window be active. In some cases the key events are actual typing operations and in other cases the key input represents shortcut key combinations.

Using SendKeys works, but obviously needs focus. I would prefer to have that operate in the background so am investivating SendMessage from user32.dll. I can see it has different signatures based on what the message code is, and this may be the origin of the problem.

Starting with

```
Dim notepad() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")
Dim actualWindow As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(notepad(0).MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", Nothing)
```

and using

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SendMessageA")>
Public Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Int32, ByVal wParam As Int32, ByVal lParam As String) As IntPtr
End Function
```

if I send

```
SendMessage(actualWindow, KeyEventType.WM_SETTEXT, 0, "Text")
```

then the editor text is replaced with "Text".

If however I use

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SendMessageA")>
Public Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Int32, ByVal wParam As Int32, ByVal lParam As Int32) As IntPtr
End Function
```

and send

```
SendMessage(actualWindow, KeyEventType.WM_KEYDOWN, &H4C, 0)
SendMessage(actualWindow, KeyEventType.WM_KEYUP, &H4C, 0)
```

or even

```
SendMessage(notepad(0).MainWindowHandle, KeyEventType.WM_KEYDOWN, &H4C, 0)
SendMessage(notepad(0).MainWindowHandle, KeyEventType.WM_KEYUP, &H4C, 0)
```

where &H4C corresponds to the 'L' key [(1.)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes), no letter 'l' appears in the editor.

I am moderately convinced that the function signatures are correct for both WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP [(2.)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown) and WM_SETTEXT [(3.)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settext). I think the problem might be one of 'focus' but am not sure how to tackle that if I want the operations to occur in the background. How can keystrokes be sent to the text editor?

The enumerations are defined as:

```
Public Enum KeyEventType As Int32
  WM_SETTEXT = &HC
  WM_KEYDOWN = &H100
  WM_KEYUP = &H101
End Enum
```

Comment: You can send `WM_CHAR`. It's almost the same: e.g., `SendMessage(actualWindow, WM_CHAR, &H4C, 1)` (`1` indicates the number of times that char is repeated).

Comment: A useful update for sending char that seemed to have worked. I'm still at a loss as to how to send control keys of why sending key down and key up doesn't achieve the same end..

Comment: [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) function.

Comment: SendInput depends on window focus I believe.

Comment: That function sends a keyboard event that the recipient application can correctly interpret when it calls `GetAsyncKeyState()`. If you want to change/set text in an app in (almost) any state, use UI Automation instead. These are your options. Don't mention `keyboard_event`, that's an old version of `SendInput`.

Comment: UI Automation sounds exactly what I want, could you expand on that?

Comment: The Edit control of Notepad (for example), provide a ValuePattern that allows to change the Text. BUT, the ValuePattern is not exposed using the managed UIAutomation (the objects .Net exposes), only the TextPattern is. This pattern doesn't allow to change the Text. You CAN use UI Automation, but only the native one can give you full access to an object 's available patterns. For example, Automation type of Notepad's `Edit` control is `Edit`, but, using this code: [...]

Comment: [...] `var notepad = AutomationElement.FromHandle([Notepad handle]) as AutomationElement; var edit = notepad.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit));`, `edit` is null. While you'll get a valid element if you set `ControlType.Document`, but now ValuePattern is not available, since Document UI element don't expose that pattern. This is forced by the .Net implementation. Using the native implementation, you can get the ValuePattern instead. The `ValuePattern.SetValue()` method can be used even when Notepad is minimized.

Comment: Note that you can also use SendMessage with `WM_GETTEXT` and `WM_SETTEXT`.